# how to hide radiobutton if other radiobutton has a specific text in it?

Tags: c#, if-statement, radio-button

I am working on a project at home that is basically a multiple choice quiz, and the answers to the radio buttons come with a string method (The questions come inside a pictureBox) and I've noticed once you answer the last question and theres no more questions to answer, the program crashes.

I'm trying to prevent this by adding 1 more picture that says something like "QUIZ OVER" and hiding the radioButtons, but I do not know how to hide the radioButtons at a specific circumstance like that.

I've tried this type of code but it did not work:

```
if (radioButton1.Text("Answer");
{
radioButton1.Hide;
radioButton2.Hide;
radioButton3.Hide;
}
```

Comment: is this asp.net or winform or ??

Comment: If this is Windows Forms, you will want to set `radioButton1.Visible = False` for each radio button. I recommend you do this when your program transitions to the final question, rather than checking the radioButton1 text like you do now.

Comment: Yes, this is windows form. So if i do this radioButton1.Visible thing, how do I make it so that in the last picture, it wont make them visible again after pressing the "next question" button?

Comment: I think you need to show more code regarding how you are storing these images and displaying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code as:

1- We don't have `Text()` method for RadioButton neither C# WinApp nor there in C# WebApp.

2- So the if Condition would be change to `if (radioButton1.Text == "Answer")`

3- So in WinForm you can use `Visable` property like `radioButton1.Visable = false`

4- At the end the code should be changed like:

```
if (radioButton1.Text == "Answer")
{
    radioButton1.Visable = false;
    radioButton2.Visable = false;
    radioButton3.Visable = false;
}
```

but if you want to check if `radioButton1` checked or not that if condition would be `if (radioButton1.Checked)`.